# Ember select element - unable to capture on change event

Tags: ember.js

Ember question - still getting used to Ember, but making progress.  Here's my issue: I have a template which references a component; the component contains a select element.  The select element displays properly, and I want to update the contents of another select element based on the selection in the first element.  However, I have not been able to capture the on change event of the first select element.  Here is the component code containing the select:

```
{{view 
  "select" 
  content=types 
  value=selectedtType 
  selection=selectedtType 
  prompt="Select Type..." 
}}
```

So I'm not sure how to reference the on change event in the component template, or where the function itself should go - the component's component.js file, or in the route.js file of the parent template.  I've done much research on this, but haven't been able to make it work yet.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, the element select code is:

Comment: {{view 
      "select" 
      content=types 
      value=selectedType 
      selection=selectedType 
      prompt="Select Type..." 
    }}

Answer (score 1):

Check this [JSBin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zeduboduqi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) In this example, I had my dependent select use a computed property as its content. This computed property's single dependent key is the `value` of the first select. If you are doing this with components, your component needs to take the computed property as the attribute that is the `select` views' `content`. Any time the first select changes, it will cause the computed property to recompute and thus update the content of the second select. Even in an example using components, this code would probably sit on the controller to keep your component generic enough that it simply takes a content for its select and displays it rather than controlling the display logic itself.

Other options, have a function that `observes` the first select value and updates a controller variable that is the second select's content. Now if you're example is more complicated in that the changing select's have different `option.valuePath` and `option.labelPath`, you can pass pass those values into your component as well.